# Jupyter notebook: connection to kernel restarts infinitely

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I just moved on to a new PC at work, installed Anaconda.
When trying to run a notebook I see the "connecting to kernel... connected to kernel" message flash to infinity with an icon saying "No connection to kernel".
It appears as if the connection gets killed after starting.

Gif: https://i.gyazo.com/6a36abdcc1c5af6e31b4666f4baef4cf.gif

Another person at work in my room has the same problem, so perhaps it has something to do with the antivirus or domain systems at work.

How can I get my jupyter to work?

Comment: Can you find the log files for jupyter?

Comment: @cricket_007 where can I locate them?

Comment: I just see them when I start jupyter from the terminal, I don't know where they are actually stored

Comment: @cricket_007 i couldn't find the log files. The console log doesn't seem to print anything suspicious

Comment: Run `jupyter kernelspec list` to see if you have kernels installed. If that does not return anything, then perhaps `jupyter` can't find any kernels to connect to. It's relatively easy to install `ipython` kernels anyway. So you may want to do that after all.

Comment: @Abdou it found a python3 kernel as intended

Comment: If you don't mind losing the history and such, you could remove the kernel and reinstall it again to see if it'll make any difference? You can also try to run the console or qtconsole (jupyter console or jupyter qtconsole) to see if they work?

Comment: @Abdou jupyter console works

Comment: Then the issue must be with `notebook` or your browser. If it is `notebook`, you will need to reinstall it again. But before doing that, have you tried the link in different browsers?

Comment: @Abdou same on other browsers. I am  sure its not the notebook

Comment: Try parsing through [this](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/7943). It mainly points to browser cache issues. Anyway, when you run `jupyter notebook` in your terminal, there should some kind of traceback that the application prints out on the terminal console. Maybe you should add that to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off the antivirus. In my case there was the Kasperskiy who was blocking the connection